# Is it possible to wrap a JS file in a func without modifying the file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo

I have a web application that uses Dojo, jQuery, and Bootstrap.  This application has a "core" codebase of .js files that cannot be modified in any way.

I'm attempting to add an external service to the application that conflicts with jQuery's global usage of $.  $ is used many times in the "core" codebase.  Is there a way to wrap these core files in an anonymous function to locally define $ = jQuery without actually modifying the files in any way? Perhaps in the way they're defined/included in the project?

I'm aware of jquery.noConflict, but this would require I change the '$' reference throughout the "core".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked my question in a very narrow and pointed way.  What I was trying to accomplish was the isolation of .js libraries required for a new external service from the .js libraries in the existing application without modifying the files.

I've found that this can be accomplished by wrapping everything related to the new service in an `<iframe>`, where you're basically embedding another document with its own namespace in the existing document to isolate the libraries from each other. For example, you could add the following within a page:

```
<iframe>
    <script src="...">
    <script src="...">
    [do stuff with above scripts here]
</iframe>
```

The global namespace in the iframe will be separate from that of the parent document.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap all of your jQuery code in an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) that allows you to use `$` as jQuery inside but also use `noConflict()` so it doesn't conflict with the other library `$`

```
(function($){
    // all your `$` code will work fine here and won't conflict with other library `$`    

})(jQuery);
```

You will see most jQuery plugins written with this wrapper also for exactly the same reason

Comment: Yes, but I cannot actually modify the .js files in the "core".  I would need to open each file and enclose everything in the IIFE, correct?

Comment: yes you would. Alternative would be modify other library to use something other than `$`